# Reference in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies

For my thesis references, When I run latex, in pdf appear like below

> Aliabadi, M. H. The Boundary Element Method, Applications in Solids and Structures, Vol. 2, J. Wiley, New York, 2002. 4
>
> Baudouin, M. de Buhan, M. and Ervedoza, S. Global Carleman estimates for waves and applications, Communications in Partial Differential Equations, 38, 823-859, 2013. 151, 153

(numbers 4 for first reference and 151,153 for second reference) are pages when appear those references.

I have used

```
\bibliographystyle{Classes/jmb} 
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 
\bibliography{References/references} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
```

In thesis.tex

I am not able to delete those numbers (For example this 4,151 and 153) in the end of my Reference. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Would deleting the _pages_ lines of the corresponding bibtex entries be an option?

Comment: Welcome to SE!    How you have setup `hyperref` package? It seems that you have in its settings `backref=page`.

Comment: If your references run over a page break, the ToC entry will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Without a proper MWE it is difficult to answer precisely.
I will offer two possible explanations/solutions

*TL;DR: look for `backref` or `pagebackref` in your TeX sources and delete it.*

## You may be using hyperref

Look for a line like one of the following in your code:

```
\usepackage[..., backref=true, ... ]{hyperref}
\usepackage[..., pagebackref, ... ]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{..., backref=true, ...}
\hypersetup{..., pagebackref, ...}
```

In case you found it you are using `hyperref` (good choice!)
with the `backref` or `pagebackref` option turned on.
Just replace `backref=true` with `backref=false` and this should solve the problem (or remove `pagebackref` or `backref` directly.

## You may be using biblatex

Look for a line like the following in your code:

```
\usepackage[..., backref=true, ... ]{biblatex}
```

In case you found it you are using `biblatex` (good choice!)
with the `backref` option turned on.
Just replace `backref=true` with `backref=false` and this should solve the problem.

## Warning

The `backref` option might be set by the document class you are using!

Answer (score 0):

The answer for how to stop the page number in front of reference,the answer is stopping the \pagebackref, for more detail look at this link http://www.khirevich.com/latex/bibliography/